# Jquery too many ajax request fired

Tags: javascript, jquery, cakephp

I have the following code build using jquery. When a user copies and pastes a a youtube url, i am suppose to extract the video id is the getVideoId(str) method in jquery. Using the id, i get the video image picture title and contents.

When the textbox->("#url") has a length more than 10, i will make a ajax request. Thus the ajax request is working. But now i have another problem. The very first time when the textbox has more than 10 characters, there is two ajax request being fired (tested using firebug). Than when the user enters more characters, there are many ajax request fired.

Thus this will slow down the process of the last ajax request. I just want to get the data of the youtube link and show a suggest where the user can add the title and content. It is like how the old facebook video video link is. Anyone has a better suggest in improving the codes?

```
jQuery(document).ready(
    function(){
        $("#url").keyup(function() {
            var $t1 =  $("#url").val();
            var $length = $t1.length;
            var $data;

            $("#title").val($length);
            $("#content").val($t1);

            if($length==0){
                alert('zero value');
                return;
            }

            if($length>10){
                $data = $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("action" => "retrieveVideoFeed"));?>',
                dataType: "json",
                data: {
                    vid: getVideoId($t1)
                },
                success: function(data) {
                                            alert('success in getting data');
                }
            });

                return;
            }

        });

            function getVideoId(str) {
                var urlRegex = /(http|https):\/\/(\w+:{0,1}\w*@)?(\S+)(:[0-9]+)?(\/|\/([\w#!:.?+=&%@!\-\/]))?/;
                if (urlRegex.test(str) && str.indexOf('v=') != -1)
                {
                    return str.split('v=')[1].substr(0, 11); // get 11-char youtube video id
                } else if (str.length == 11) {
                    return str;
                }
                return null;
            }
    }
);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could cache the calls and use blur event and not keyup: you are firing a lot of AJAX call because keyup() fires an event each time a key is pressed, you should use blur that fires an event when an input loses focus.
If you cache the calls in an object you can avoid a lot of repeated calls

```
   var cacheUrl = {};

   $("#url").blur(function() {
        var $t1 =  $("#url").val();
        var $length = $t1.length;
        var $data;

        $("#title").val($length);
        $("#content").val($t1);

        if($length==0){
            alert('zero value');
            return;
        }

        if(cacheUrls[$t1] !== undefined && $length>10){
            $data = $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $this->Html->url(array("action" => "retrieveVideoFeed"));?>',
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                vid: getVideoId($t1)
            },
            success: function(data) {
                    //save the data to avoid a future call
                    cacheUrls[$t1] = data;
                                        alert('success in getting data');
            }
        });

            return;
        }elseif ($length>10){
            //you already have the data in  cacheUrls[$t1] 
        }

    });
```

EDIT if you want to use the submit key to start the search you could trigger the blur event when you press enter like this:

```
$("#url").keypress(function(e){
    if(e.which == 13){
       $(this).blur();
       return false;
    }
});
```

Comment: I put keyup because i want to fire the event everytime the user changes the url. But you are right. But when i use onblur, the user has to click somewhere outside to get the ajax to run. How can i play with the enter button. Could you help in that?

Comment: @madi i edited my answer: basically you could check wich key is pressed and trigger the blur event if that character is enter

Comment: @madi cacheUrl saves the data of the ajax call so that if you don't make the same call twice for the same request. Before making a call i check if the call has been made before (`cacheUrls[$t1] !== undefined`) and then i save the data in the cache (`cacheUrls[$t1] = data;`) so that i can use it later

Comment: i tried the .keypress with the enter feature but after my enter, the page refreshes .....arrrrrhhh....anyway to solve?

Comment: I placed the textbox outside the form and it works fine now :)

Comment: I suggest you open a new question for it, but i think that the problem is that your input field is inside a form. You should `return false;` to prevent the form from submitting, i updated my answer

Comment: @madi ok you got it before i suggested it to you, do as you did that is ok!

Comment: i wish that i can have your email address :(

Answer (score 2):

I think many ajax requests are fired because you are using `$("#url").keyup(function()` 
so that for every key event in url input the particular funciton will exectue.So, as per i know better to use focusout method instead of keyup.

Answer (score 1):

If you stay with the `keyup`-Event you maybe want to use an [ajaxmanager-plugin](http://www.protofunc.com/scripts/jquery/ajaxManager/) for jQuery which can manage queues or limits the number of simultaneous requests.

```
    $.manageAjax.create('myAjaxManager', {
        queue: true,
        cacheResponse: false,
        maxRequests: 1,
        queue: 'clear'
    });
    ....
    if($length>10){
        $data = $.manageAjax.add({ ...
```

This will prevent having alot of ajaxrequests active at the same time when the user is typing. As soon as he stops the request will not aborted and the results will show up.